# extract array from web fetched json file python

Tags: python, json, web, fetch

i want to fetch live quotes from this page in python 3
[link](https://www.edelweiss.in/market/option-chain)

the quotes here is stored in json file in array "JsonData"
i want to get the value stored in LTP inside the json file

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json


url = ("https://ewmw.edelweiss.in/api/Market/Process/GetFutureValue/BANKNIFTY/05%20Apr%202018")
response = urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
y = json.loads(data['JsonData'])
print(y)
```

Comment: And what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
y = json.loads(data['JsonData'])
```

with

```
y = json.loads(data.decode('string-escape').strip('"'))
print(y)                                 #And then access the required variable.
print(y["JsonData"])
```

**Note**: Your data is escaped. that is why i have used `.decode('string-escape').strip('"')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try ast :

But before using eval() read this [post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) from NedBat

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import ast

url = ("https://ewmw.edelweiss.in/api/Market/Process/GetFutureValue/BANKNIFTY/05%20Apr%202018")
response = urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
load_data= ast.literal_eval(data)
convert_to = json.loads(load_data)


print(convert_to['JsonData'])
```

output:

```
{'LTP': '24339.3', 'ChgPer': '-0.68', 'ArticleUrl': '', 'Url': '/quotes/index-future/BANKNIFTY~2018-04-26', 'CoCode': 'BANKNIFTY', 'Date': '2018-04-26T00:00:00', 'Chg': '-165.55'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval as suggested below, but that's not such a good thing to do, really. So you can go with this:

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get('https://ewmw.edelweiss.in/api/Market/Process/GetFutureValue/BANKNIFTY/05%20Apr%202018').json()
data = json.loads(r)
print(data['JsonData'])
```

Or alternatively, if you insist on using urllib, then just add another `y = json.loads(y)`, it's not a good solution, so you want to change that later, but a bit better than eval. Complete code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = ("https://ewmw.edelweiss.in/api/Market/Process/GetFutureValue/BANKNIFTY/05%20Apr%202018")
response = urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
y = json.loads(data)
y = json.loads(y)
print(y['JsonData'])
```

If it was me though, I'd go with the first one, cleaner, shorter, better.

Comment: the code worked successfully for the previous url however when i use this link. i get key error when accessing arrays in json  https://ewmw.edelweiss.in/api/Market/Process/QuoteOption/BANKNIFTY~2018040524700CE